# Calling same javascript function from different .Net User Control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, user-controls

I have a page and inside the page, I have 2 user controls. 
Both user control will include the same .js and call the same method (but pass different args into the method) from code behind.
But only one of the user controls can able to execute the js.

User control 1

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Page, typeof(Page), "AutoSlider", "../../../Themes/Ooredoo/js/Slider.js");
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "AutoSliderInit", "$(document).ready(function(){ SliderAutoSlide('ul#sliderImage'); });", true);
```

User control 2

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Page, typeof(Page), "AutoSlider", "../../../Themes/Ooredoo/js/Slider.js");
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "AutoSliderInit", "$(document).ready(function(){ SliderAutoSlide('ul#smallSliderImage'); });", true);
```

When I tried to inspect element, I can only find UserControl1 javascript but not UserControl2.

What should I do in order for both usercontrols able to call the same js (pass diff args)?

Comment: 1. You will see this script after its excuted so make sure you are calling that one in a page load of user control and then refer first answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're registering the ClinetScriptBlock with the same `Key` but with different functions

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "AutoSliderInit", "$(document).ready(function(){ SliderAutoSlide('ul#sliderImage'); });", true);
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "AutoSliderInitSmall", "$(document).ready(function(){ SliderAutoSlide('ul#smallSliderImage'); });", true);
                                                                           ^ Change the Key
```

Comment: Now I know why I need the key :)  haha